# exclude full word with javascript regex word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

I'am looking to exclude matches that contain a specific word or phrase. For example, how could I match only lines 1 and 3? the `\b` word boundary does not work intuitively like I expected.

```
foo.js            # match
foo_test.js       # do not match
foo.ts            # match
fun_tset.js       # match
fun_tset_test.ts  # do not match
```

**UPDATE**

What I want to exclude is strings ending explicitly with `_test` before the extension. At first I had something like `[^_test]`, but that also excludes any combination of those characters (like line 3).

Comment: The [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) does not match between `_` and `t`. If you don't want to match where `_test` is a part of the string you could use a negative lookahead `^(?!.*_test).+$`

Comment: and why those two should match? What are their differences?

Comment: can you specify the criteria for matching?

Comment: updated with more details... sry, was up late when i posted this

Answer (score 2):

Regex: `^(?!.*_test\.).*$`

Working examples: https://regex101.com/r/HdGom7/1

Why it works: uses negative lookahead to check if `_test.` exists somewhere in the string, and if so doesn't match it.

Comment: You look like an expert. I wonder why my pattern didn't worked: `/\b(\w+)(?!_test)\.(\w+)\b/g` ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @pretzelhammer's answer, it looks like you want to grab strings that are file names ending in ts or js:

```
^(?!.*_test)(.*\.[jt]s)
```

The expression in the first parentheses is a negative lookahead that excludes any strings with `_test`, the second parentheses matches any strings that end in a period, followed by `[jt]` (j or t), followed by `s`.